# Assigning one primitive variable to another vs a reference variable to another

Tags: java, primitive-types, object-reference

I would like to understand how primitive and object reference variable behaves differently. I have used the below code from *OCA/OCP Java SE7* by Kathy Sierra as an example:

```
public class VariableTesting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 10;
        System.out.println("a= " + a);

        int b = a;
        b = 30;
        System.out.println("a= " + a + " after change it to b and b is " + b);

        Dimension a1 = new Dimension(5, 10);
        System.out.println("a1.height = " + a1.height);

        Dimension b1 = a1;
        b1.height = 30;

        System.out.println("a1.height= " + a1.height + " after change to b1");
    }
}
```

In the above piece of code, I'm getting the value of `a = 10;` before and after changing the value of `b`.

The output for the primitive variable case is:

```
a = 10
a = 10 after change it to b and b is 30
```

However, in object reference variable I'm getting a different value once I change the value of `b1.height = 30;`

The output for the reference variable case is:

```
a1.height = 10
a1.height = 30 after change to b1
```

It is mentioned in the book that in both case the bit pattern is copied and a new copy is placed. If this is true, then why we are getting different behavior?

Comment: Read this to clear all your doubts : http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~mrmiller/15-110/Handouts/primitiveVsObject.pdf

Comment: @JunedAhsan Thanks , this hand out was very helpful

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the underpinning difference between a reference and a primitive.  In both cases, you're getting the actual *value*, but only in the case of an object do you have a chance to impact the result of any other usages of it.

Let's walk through the code.

```
int a = 10;
int b = a;
```

These two declarations are saying the following:

- Assign the value 10 to an int identifier called `a`.
- Assign the value of `a` to an int identifier called `b`.

So far, so good.  Nowhere do we say that `a` is referenced by `b`; we're only taking values.

If we declare:

```
b = 30;
```

We're saying **take the value of 30 and assign it to the identifier `b`.**

We don't do anything with `a` at that point; it already contains the value `10`.  This is why `a` and `b` are different.

Now, when we get to the object, things don't really change on the surface...

```
Dimension a1 = new Dimension(5, 10);
Dimension b1 = a1;
```

We translate this as:

- Assign the value of instantiation of a new Dimension with (int) parameters 5 and 10 to a `Dimension` identifier `a1`.
- Assign the value of `a1` to a `Dimension` identifier `b1`.

**We're still assigning *values* here**, since Java is [pass-by-value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/1079354).  The kicker here is that in Java, the value of an object is still a reference to that object.

By the above example, `a1` and `b1` are pointing to the *same instance*.

Now, when we state this:

```
b1.height = 30;
```

We're actually saying:

- Assign the value 30 to the field `height` dereferenced through the value `b1`.

We're still referring to the value of `b1` here, which is tied to `a1`.  This is why you see the difference; because `a1` and `b1` refer to the same value (which is the same reference), any change done through the identifier `b1` is reflected through `a1`.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation. Help me understand a lot better

Answer (score 3):

#### There is only one instance

When you say

```
Dimension b1= a1; // <-- assigns reference of a1 to b1.
```

you assign the reference address that `a1` refers to *to* `b1`. Thus, when you modify the `height` field through `b1` you also modify `a1`.

```
 b1.height=30; // <-- a1.height = 30
```

#### Create another instance

If you want `b1` to be a unique referene, then you use `new`.

```
 Dimension b1= new Dimension(a1.width, a1.height); // <-- creates a new Dimension
```